# C application HTTP failing when re-establishing a connection

Tags: c, http, microcontroller

I'm developping an application which will run on a bosch device - XDK - http://xdk.bosch-connectivity.com/.

At this moment, I have a task which implements an http client and sends POST requests to a server. However, the main purpose of my application is to be able to move between areas with network coverage/no coverage. This means that I'm constantly suspending/re-starting the task that implements the http client.

So I'm having problem with the http client in the following scenario: I start the application in a region with coverage, then I move to a region with no coverage and finally, go back again to a region with coverage. That's here I'm getting problems. From that moment, I can't connect anymore with the http client.

I'll post here pieces of code of my application so that you can suggest me some alterations to solve the problem.
All the functions such as HttpClient_initRequest, HttpMsg_setReqUrl, Msg_prependPartFactory, ..., belong to the API provided for the XDK.

```
void appInitSystem(xTimerHandle xTimer) {
    (void) (xTimer);

    return_t retValue = FAILURE;
    retcode_t wlanRet = RC_PLATFORM_ERROR;

    wlanRet = wlan_init();
    if (wlanRet != RC_OK){
        printf("Network init/connection failed %i \r\n", wlanRet);
        assert(0);
    }

    wlanRet = PAL_initialize();
    if (wlanRet != RC_OK){
        printf("PAL and network initialize %i \r\n", wlanRet);
        assert(0);
    }

    PAL_socketMonitorInit();

    /* start http client */
    wlanRet = HttpClient_initialize();
    if (wlanRet != RC_OK){
        printf("Failed to initialize http client\r\n ");
        assert(0);
    }

    if (RC_OK != PAL_getIpaddress((uint8_t*) "52.58.121.5", &destAddr))
       return;

    retValue = createTasks();
    if (retValue == FAILURE)
        assert(0);
}

retcode_t wlan_init(void) {
    WLI_connectStatus_t retconnection;
    NCI_ipSettings_t myIpSettings;
    char ipAddress[PAL_IP_ADDRESS_SIZE] = { 0 };
    Ip_Address_T* IpaddressHex = Ip_getMyIpAddr();
    WLI_connectSSID_t connectSSID;
    WLI_connectPassPhrase_t connectPassPhrase;
    NCI_return_t ReturnValue = NCI_FAILURE;
    int32_t Result = INT32_C(-1);
    if (WLI_SUCCESS != WLI_init())
        return (RC_PLATFORM_ERROR);

    connectSSID = (WLI_connectSSID_t) WLAN_CONNECT_WPA_SSID;
    connectPassPhrase = (WLI_connectPassPhrase_t) WLAN_CONNECT_WPA_PASS;

    /*DHCP */
    ReturnValue = NCI_setIpDhcp(NULL);
    if (ReturnValue != NCI_SUCCESS){
        printf("Error in setting IP to DHCP\n\r");
        return (RC_PLATFORM_ERROR);
    }

    if (WLI_SUCCESS == WLI_connectWPA(connectSSID, connectPassPhrase, NULL){

        ReturnValue = NCI_getIpSettings(&myIpSettings);
        if (NCI_SUCCESS == ReturnValue){
            *IpaddressHex = Basics_htonl(myIpSettings.ipV4);
            Result = Ip_convertAddrToString(IpaddressHex, ipAddress);
            if (Result < 0){
                printf("Couldn't convert the IP address to string format \r\n ");
                return (RC_PLATFORM_ERROR);
            }
            printf("Connected to WPA network successfully \r\n ");
            printf(" Ip address of the device %s \r\n ", ipAddress);
            return (RC_OK);
        }
        else{
            printf("Error in getting IP settings\n\r");
            return (RC_PLATFORM_ERROR);
        }

   }
   else
      return (RC_PLATFORM_ERROR);

   return RC_OK;
}


/* Task which calls the nttp client */
void dataOffload(void* handle) {
    (void) handle;

     for (;;){
         ....
         http_connServer(NULL);
         ...
         vTaskDelay(1000/portTICK_RATE_MS);
     }
 }

void http_connServer(void * pvParameters){

    retcode_t rc = RC_OK;
    Msg_T* msg_ptr;
    Ip_Port_T destPort = (Ip_Port_T) DEST_PORT_NUMBER;
    static Callable_T SentCallable;
    char const *url_ptr = "/";  
    Callable_T * Callable_pointer;
    Callable_pointer = Callable_assign(&SentCallable, http_callbackOnSent);
    if (Callable_pointer == NULL)
        return;

    rc = HttpClient_initRequest(&destAddr, Ip_convertIntToPort(destPort), &msg_ptr);
    if (rc != RC_OK || msg_ptr == NULL)
        return;

    rc = Msg_prependPartFactory( msg_ptr, &http_setContent);
    if (rc != RC_OK) 
      return;

    rc = HttpMsg_setReqUrl(msg_ptr, url_ptr);
    if (rc != RC_OK) 
        return;

    HttpMsg_setReqMethod(msg_ptr, Http_Method_Post);

    rc = HttpClient_pushRequest(msg_ptr, &SentCallable,
        http_clientResponseCallback);
    if (rc != RC_OK){
        printf("Failed HttpClient_pushRequest \r\n  ");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: What HTTP related library are you using? On what operating system? You should mention it in your question. For client HTTP, I suggest [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). For server HTTP, I suggest [libonion](http://coralbits.com/libonion/). HTTP is complex enough to avoid losing your time to code your own HTTP implementation.

Comment: Hi @BasileStarynkevitch thanks for the advice, I've just edited my post. I'm using a bosch device - XDK. I'm using the functions they provide so we can trust that all functions like HttpClient_initRequest were well implemented.

Comment: http://xdk.bosch-connectivity.com/community is probably a better place to ask. But be specific and give not only the above code snippet, but also some more context & motivation.